# Hacer aplicación desktop que sea como una mascara para la pantalla

Tags: c#

Necesito hacer una aplicación de escritorio que al abrirla a pantalla completa oculte parte de la pantalla (digamos el monitor) con color negro u otro, y que por ej en el centro tenga un cuadrado donde se vea lo que sea que este en la pc en ese momento, por ej si detrás de la aplicación hay una ventana abierta o un documento que se vea y se pueda trabajar en esa area visible. Es posible eso en c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyForm.Opacity = 0.83;

this.MyForm= System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;

Ejecutas tu load a pantalla completa, puedes utilizar algún elemento como el panel o cualquier otro y darle una opacidad, si es muy transparente podrás ver tu escritorio

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar como dicho código soluciona el problema planteado?

Comment: Ejecutas tu load a pantalla completa, puedes utilizar algún elemento como el panel o cualquier otro y darle una opacidad, si es muy transparente podrás ver tu escritorio..

Comment: Por favor agrega dicha información a tu respuesta (editándola).